# Find Posterior distribution with uniform prior and uniform likelihood

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, uniform-distribution, bayesian

I have a question on Bayesian statistics. Let's consider a prior $\pi(\theta) \sim Un(\theta\mid10,20)$, where $\theta$ is an unknown weight and the problem is modelled $Un(x\mid\theta - \frac{1}{2},\theta + \frac{1}{2} )$. I want to find the posterior $\theta$ for a single value $x=12$.

***My solution:***

I know from first principles I am trying to use Bayes formula:

$$
\pi(\theta\mid x) = \frac{f(x\mid\theta) \times \pi(\theta) }{\pi(x)}
$$
where,

- $\pi(\theta\mid x)$ : posterior
- $f(x\mid \theta)$: likelihood
- $\pi(\theta)$: prior
- $\pi(x)$: normalization constant.

So from $P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B\mid A)P(B)}{P(A)}$
$$
\text{Posterior} = \frac{ \text{Likelihood} \times \text{Prior}  }{\text{Normalization constant} }
$$

In my case where $x=12$:

I think

- $\pi(\theta\mid x=12) = Un(\theta\mid  11.5, 12.5)$ for posterior

from

- $f(x\mid \theta) = 1 \,\forall \,\theta$: likelihood, since $f(x\mid \theta)  = \prod^{n} Un(\theta - \frac{1}{2},\theta + \frac{1}{2}) =\frac{1}{1^{n}}  = \frac{1}{1^{n}} = 1$
- $\pi(\theta) = \frac{1}{10}$: prior

Comment: Instead of $f(x \mid \theta) = 1 \forall \theta$ I would say $f(x \mid \theta) = 1$ if $\theta \in [x - 0.5, x + 0.5]$ and $f(x \mid \theta) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Alex, is the posterior correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct